# OPEN CV iOS installation

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, image-processing

> I am installing the opencv in my system followings the command given by open cv  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html
>   I am getting this error Please let me know what I am missing.

```
anil-Mac-2s-Mac-mini:opencv pws-mac-2$ python platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios
Executing: ['cmake', '-GXcode', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/pws-mac-2/Desktop/opencv/platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-iPhoneOS_Xcode.cmake', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install', '-DENABLE_NEON=ON', '/Users/pws-mac-2/Desktop/opencv', '-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fembed-bitcode', '-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fembed-bitcode'] in /Users/pws-mac-2/Desktop/opencv/ios/build/armv7-iPhoneOS

============================================================
ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
============================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 183, in <module>
b.build(args.out)
File "platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 87, in build
self.buildOne(t[0], t[1], mainBD, cmake_flags)
File "platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 105, in buildOne
execute(cmakecmd, cwd = builddir)
File "platforms/ios/build_framework.py", line 34, in execute
retcode = check_call(cmd, cwd = cwd)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am getting this error Please let me know how to resolve . . .

Comment: what's in the OpenCV directory? did you make sure the file exists ?

Comment: Yes file exists . . I have checked manually

Comment: @nour question is edited please check now

Comment: Have you installed python?

Comment: Yes Python 2.7.10  is installed in my system . . .I am using mac

Comment: Have you installed cmake?

Comment: I have installed cmake

Comment: Because this is the exact error I get when I don't have `cmake` installed.

Comment: @petesh let me know how you installed cmake

Comment: I can try it with your way

Comment: `brew install cmake` - I'm using the [homebrew](http://brew.sh) package management system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98200/discussion-between-anil-solanki-and-petesh).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This error happens because `cmake` is either (a) not installed or (b) not on the user's path.

In this case, the OP had downloaded the `cmake` gui application [from cmake.org](https://cmake.org/download/), and copied it to `/Applications`. This app doesn't add the path to the binaries automatically, which is why the script couldn't find `cmake`.

By adding the path to the cmake binaries (bash syntax):

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin
```

the OP was able to successfully build opencv.

Most package managers - e.g. [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [macports](http://macports.org/) whould have automatically added a path to the user's profile that would have permitted it to run without having to modify the path any more.

Answer (score 5):

You may need to install CMake

```
My-Mac: opencv$ brew install cmake
```