# Installing OpenCV for xCode issue

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, shell, opencv

I could not install/build openCV for xCode. I get this following error in the last command given in this installation document link. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html

Error is   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd

When giving python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios command. Can you please suggest help on this ? Have installed cmake using homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was facing the same problem but was resolved.Please check out same question asked by me.A guy answered this question.Please check out this link and let me know if it helps

[OPEN CV iOS installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328123/open-cv-ios-installation)

Comment: I came after checking this, I have a question. In the command PATH=$PATH:/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin, the path you give is the application folder path where we have installed cmake using home brew?

Comment: Okay, do we have to give this command after that ? My cmake is installed. 
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin 
And what 'PATH' should I give here ?

Answer (score 0):

After cmake installaion, I directly downloaded openCV for mac and used its framework.